# Writing an interpreter for an imperative language in Haskell

Tags: haskell, interpreter, typechecking

I am trying to build an interpreter for a C-like language in Haskell. I have so far written and combined small monadic parsers following [this](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/monparsing.pdf) paper, hence so far I can generate an AST representation of a program. I defined the abstract syntax as follows:

```
data LangType = TypeReal | TypeInt | TypeBool | TypeString deriving (Show)
type Id = String

data AddOp = Plus | Minus | Or deriving (Show)
data RelOp = LT | GT | LTE | GTE | NEq | Eq deriving (Show)
data MultOp = Mult | Div | And deriving (Show)
data UnOp = UnMinus | UnNot deriving (Show)
data BinOp = Rel RelOp | Mul MultOp | Add AddOp deriving (Show)

data AST = Program [Statement] deriving (Show)
data Block = StatsBlock [Statement] deriving (Show)
data Statement = VariableDecl Id LangType Expression
               | Assignment Id Expression
               | PrintStatement Expression
               | IfStatement Expression Block Block
               | WhileStatement Expression Block
               | ReturnStatement Expression
               | FunctionDecl Id LangType FormalParams Block 
               | BlockStatement Block 
               deriving (Show)
data Expression = RealLiteral Double
                | IntLiteral Int
                | BoolLiteral Bool
                | StringLiteral String
                | Unary UnOp Expression
                | Binary BinOp Expression Expression
                | FuncCall Id [Expression]
                | Var Id
                deriving (Show)
data FormalParams = IdentifierType [(Id, LangType)] deriving (Show)
```

I have yet to type-check my AST and build the interpreter to evaluate expressions and execute statements. My questions are the following:

> 1. Does the abstract syntax make sense/can it be improved? In particular, I've been running into a recurring problem. In the EBNF of this language I'm trying to interpret, a `WhileStatement` consists of an `Expression` (which I have no problem with) and a `Block`,  which in the EBNF happens to be a `Statement` just like `WhileStatement`, and so I cannot refer to `Block` from my `WhileStatement`. I've worked around this by defining a separate data type `Block` (as is shown in the above code), but am not sure if this is the best way. I'm finding defining data types quite confusing.
> 2. Since I have to type-check my AST and evaluate/execute, do I implement these separately or can I define some function which does them both at the same time?

Any general tips on how I should go about type-checking and interpreting the language would also be greatly appreciated. Since the language has variable and function declarations, I am thinking of implementing some sort of symbol table, although again I am struggling with defining the type for this. So far I've tried

```
    import qualified Data.Map as M

    data Value = RealLit Double | IntLit Int | BoolLit Bool | StringLit String | Func [FormalParams] String 
                 deriving (Show)
    type TermEnv = M.Map String Value
```

but I'm unsure whether I should be using my `LangType` from before.

Comment: I am not sure what the difficulty you are having with `WhileStatement` is -- there's nothing in principle wrong with referring to a nested statement while interpreting another statement.  The typical way to do this would be to have `data Statement = WhileStatement Expression Statement | Block [Statement] | ...`; that is, a block is just a statement that happens to contain multiple statements.

Comment: @luqui I've thought of doing that, but `Statement` is more broad than `Block`. In this particular example, I could actually replace `Block` in `WhileStatement` with `Statement`, even though `Block` in my EBNF is not technically a list of `Statement`s but a list of `Statement`s _with curly brackets_, but I could easily account for that when parsing `WhileStatement`. Maybe this wasn't the best example, imagine if `Block` was defined completely differently, and `WhileStatement` has a `Block`, is the way I did it the right way to go about it?

Comment: usually purely syntactic differences such as "with curly brackets" are gone by the time you get to the AST -- such differences are only known to the parser.  But yeah this seems fine and pretty idiomatic.  Still not sure what the difficulty you were facing is...

Comment: @luqui If the abstract syntax is fine, I'm now kind of stuck as to how to proceed with the type-checking and evaluation. I've seen some simple implementations of type-checkers, however they were quite verbose. Maybe I could use a combination of the State and Error monads but I'm not sure how to implement those for this context. Would appreciate some general pointing in the right direction.

Comment: @sigma Were you able to manage to implement the language completely? I'm writing my own but I'm having a bit of trouble.

Comment: @JiangShi I did manage to write a type-checker and evaluator, albeit with a few limitations.

Comment: @sigma Do you have a repo for it? I would love to check it out

Comment: @JiangShi I don't unfortunately, perhaps we could communicate some other way?

Comment: @sigma Any suggestions that isn't just leaving our details on SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your question in the comments about how to proceed with type checking and evaluation.

If you don't have to do inference or polymorphism, type checking is pretty simple. Also type checking and evaluation mirror each other pretty closely in these conditions.

Begin by defining a monad with the features you need.  For a type checker, you will need

- A *type environment*, i.e. a [`Reader`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html)`(Map Id LangType)` component, to keep track of the types of local variables.
- An *error* ability, e.g. [`Except`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html)`String`.

So you could define a monad like

```
type TypeEnv = Map.Map Id LangType
type TC = ReaderT TypeEnv (Except String)
```

And then your typechecker function would look like:

```
typeCheck :: AST -> TC ()
```

(We return `()` because there is nothing interesting to be gained from the typechecking process besides knowing whether the program passed.)

This will be largely structurally inductive, e.g.

```
typeCheck (Program stmt) = -- typecheckStmt each statement*

typeCheckStmt :: Statement -> TC ()
typeCheckStmt (VariableDecl v type defn) = ...
typeCheckStmt (Assignment v exp) = do
    Just t <- asks (Map.lookup v)
    t' <- typeCheckExp exp
    when (t /= t') $ throwError "Types do not match"
...

-- Return the type of a composite expression to use elsewhere
typeCheckExp :: Expression -> TC LangType
...
```

There will be a bit of finesse required to make sure that variable declarations in a list of statements can be seen by later statements in the same list. I will leave that as a puzzle.  (Hint: see the `local` function to provide an updated environment within a scope.)

---

Evaluation is a similar story.  You're correct that you need a type of run-time values.  Without some cleverness that you are probably not ready for (and is of questionable utility even if you were) there is not really a way to use `LangType` in `Value`, so you're on the right track.

You will need a monad that supports keeping track of the values of variables and the ability to do whatever else your language needs.  To start I recommend

```
type Eval = StateT (Map Id Value) IO
```

and proceed structurally as before.  There will again be some finesse required when handling variable scopes and shadowing, and you may need to change the environment type or mess with your `Value` type a bit to accommodate these subtleties, but thinking through these problems is important.  Start simple, don't try to implement typechecking and evaluation for your whole language at once.